# C# Python input method returns an error

Tags: c#, python, compiler-errors, ironpython

I've just started to learn IronPython and I tried the code below which returned `IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'name 'hello' is not defined'`.
**Code:**

```
var py = Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = py.CreateScope();
py.Execute(@"word = input('Input string\n')", scope);
var input = scope.GetVariable("word");
py.Execute("print " + input);
```

Console run ok, then it asked me to `Input string`, and I typed into `"hello"`. And then it fired off the above error message. Then I tried this one just to see if it does without `input` method:

```
py.Execute(@"x = 2 + 3", scope);
py.Execute("print 'result'," + scope.GetVariable("x"));
```

So that one was ok.

Can someone please explain why can I not retrieve a variable from `"input"` method? and why is it an `UnboundNameException`?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you're using Python 2, then you need to use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Why do you have c# tag in the question ?

Comment: is `wrod` a typo here: `var input = scope.GetVariable("wrod");`

Comment: @srf yeah, it's a typo. Sorry about that!

Comment: @khelwood I tried `raw_input` and now it returns `IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'global name 'hello' is not defined'`. But now this error is at the line where `print` method is.

Comment: Have you tried any name other than input?

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia yep, tried other words but it still returns same error which I pointed out to @khelwood. I guess there is something to do with passing `word` variable to `print` method but I can't get my head around how to tackle it.

Comment: clearly you typed in "hello" as your input - so your item became "print hello" .. you likely wanted as simple as print word.. while you read the value of input to c# ..  or you wanted something like "print '" + intput +"'"

Comment: @Thatshowweroll apologies if I did it wrong but I thought if did it through C# so it somehow connected to it?

Comment: @BugFinder yes, I did "hello". I then tried to `py.Execute("print " + scope.GetVariable("word"))` given that `word` is the variable where my `hello` string is held. And it fires off same error `global name "hello" is not defined`.

Comment: because you're sending the value to be printed but like a variable!

Comment: @vlad it is completely python question however it is ok to put c#, my bad.

Comment: @Thatshowweroll no worries! Cheers!

Comment: @BugFinder yes! I got it when I read your post below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having never worked with ironpython the answer lies within your own code.

your code:

```
py.Execute(@"word = input('Input string\n')", scope); (I type in dog)
var input = scope.GetVariable("word");
py.Execute("print " + input);
```

results in that last line saying py.Execute("print dog") ... but there is no dog varaible.

yet here:

```
py.Execute("print 'result'," + scope.GetVariable("x"));
```

You know to encapsulate text in quotes..

Id speculate that

```
py.Execute("print " + input);
```

Should read

```
py.Execute("print '" + input + "'");
```

Which results in print 'dog'

Comment: yes! You're absolutely right! It worked like a charm! Those bloody quotes! :))) Thanks for making my day! You're a star!

Comment: See you had the answer.. I havent ever coded in python, but you had the logic in front of you to answer it  The reason print 'result',<somevariable contents> probably works is because its a comma not a +

Comment: Hah! My gosh! I didn't even notice that LOL that's because you're a pro and am a complete beginner. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I now get to annoy people by adding pyton to my list .. awesome - age 16 I was sitting in a university area pootling about on unix, bloke next to me ranted, F'd and blinded, i gave in and asked what was wrong. He pointed at his code.. I suggested a fix, I was right.. i had heard of the language, never used it, still havent, and fixed his PhD project.. so.. now I  have 2 .. go me

Comment: Good to have such folks like yourself on this website! Yous are an asset ;) Take care!